# Combining conditional classifier probabilities

Tags: classification, probability, probability-theory

I have several document classifiers trying to predict the correct document type for a document. For a given file, each classifier outputs a list of the probabilities of each document type. I'm trying to combine the predictions of these different classifiers into a single probability list.

As I want to be able to manually decide how trusted / impactful every classifier will be, I started using a weighted average to combine the predictions.

If we look at an example with three classifiers (One, Two, Three) and three document types (T1, T2, T3). With the weighted average method, I would compute 
`Presult(T1) = (1 * Pone(T1) + 2 * Ptwo(T1) + 2 * Pthree(T1)) / (1 + 2 + 2) = 0.5`

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Classifier ║ Coefficient ║  P(T1)  ║  P(T2)  ║  P(T3)  ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ One        ║      1      ║   0.7   ║   0.1   ║   0.2   ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Two        ║      2      ║   0.8   ║   0.0   ║   0.2   ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Three      ║      2      ║   0.1   ║   0.2   ║   0.7   ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Results    ║      /      ║   0.5   ║   0.1   ║   0.4   ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

This simple approach seems to work, but things get more complicated.

Actually, some of my classifiers are specialized: they do no apply to the entire input domain (the full list of document types), but only to a subdomain. For example, I might have a classifier that, given an IRS form, can determine the respective probabilities of the document being a W-2, a W-3 or a 1040 form. In that case, the output probabilities are conditional probabilities.

Let's say that classifiers Two and Three are specialized classifiers. Classifier Two only apply to types T1 and T2, and classifier Three only applies to type T2 and T3. My new table could look something like this:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Classifier ║ Coefficient ║  P(T1)  ║  P(T2)  ║  P(T3)  ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ One        ║      1      ║   0.5   ║   0.3   ║   0.2   ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Two        ║      2      ║   0.2   ║   0.8   ║   N/A   ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Three      ║      2      ║   N/A   ║   0.4   ║   0.6   ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Results    ║      /      ║    ?    ║    ?    ║    ?    ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

However, in that case, it does not really makes sense to use a weighted average to compute the final probabilities, because we would be adding probabilities on different domains. I've tried drafting several approaches but could not find anything adapted. Do you have any idea or pointers to existing methods to combine these different predictions into one?

Thank you for reading ;)

PS: I'm sorry for the lack of mathematical formalism of the question, but wasn't sure how to write it correctly.

Comment: This is a great question, of enduring interest; a web search for "combining classifiers" turns up a lot of resources. This question is better suited to stats.stackexchange.com, though.

Comment: Thanks! I've posted here as well: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430819/combining-conditional-classifier-probabilities. I've looked at the different results for "combining classifiers" but they seems focused on the case where they all have the same input domain. I'll keep digging :)